# Combining pdfs into one pdf

Tags: java, pdf, arrays

I have a web app that I am changing to use xPressions from EMC2. There is a point where xPressions returns a pdf document inside a java servlet. Before we added xPressions, we would combine several of these pdfs into one large pdf and send it back to the user/screen. But xPressions can only process one pdf at a time. It is returning the pdf as a byte[] array. So I am trying to find a way to take the byte[] arrays and combine them into one large pdf to send back to the user/screen. Before we had xPressions we were using an old version of Big Faceless (bfo.com) to combine the individual pdfs into one pdf in the servlet. I have not been able to get the byte[] array to a valid pdf using the old bfo.com software. I have searched on Google and here on stack overflow for another technique. I have found answers that are close but most are using Linux or c#. Also, these pdfs are created inside the java servlet and are not existing on a hard drive where I could read them in and convert them. I have to take the byte[] array and work with that. So, does anyone have any ideas for me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: There are multiple general purpose PDF libraries available for Java. Most of them offer PDF merging routines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for merging your pdf files. PDFMergerUtility class has a method [addSource](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/PDFMergerUtility.html#addSource(java.io.InputStream)) which takes in an inputstream, you can convert the byte array to inputstream and add that as a source.

```
PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
merger.addSource(...);
merger.addSource(...);
merger.setDestinationFileName(...);
merger.mergeDocuments();
```